# Add Missing Hyphens on first line when hyphen only exists on second line with regex

Tags: regex

Need to ADD missing hyphen on first line when hyphen only exists on second line only:

```
167
00:06:59,794 --> 00:07:01,379
Well, I would like to see
your face as soon as possible.

168
00:07:01,421 --> 00:07:03,048
Really?
- If that's possible, yeah.

169
00:07:03,089 --> 00:07:04,007
- Really?
- Mm-hmm.

170
00:07:04,049 --> 00:07:05,550
I wanna see your face.
- Okay.

171
00:07:05,592 --> 00:07:07,427
Let's just order so we can get
the business out of the way,
```

Here is closest I was able to come, problem is that it grabs it all (don't laugh):

```
Find:   ([A-Z][\S\s]+)(?=^-\B)
Replace: - $1\r\n-
```

The CORRECT end results would be as follows with both lines having hyphens:

```
167
00:06:59,794 --> 00:07:01,379
Well, I would like to see
your face as soon as possible.

168
00:07:01,421 --> 00:07:03,048
- Really?
- If that's possible, yeah.

169
00:07:03,089 --> 00:07:04,007
- Really?
- Mm-hmm.

170
00:07:04,049 --> 00:07:05,550
- I wanna see your face.
- Okay.

171
00:07:05,592 --> 00:07:07,427
Let's just order so we can get
the business out of the way,
```

Thanks in Advance,
Hank

Comment: More ideas: [Replace `^\b(?=[^\d-].*\n-)` to `- `](https://regex101.com/r/gE3MiO/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
^([A-Z])(?=.*\r?\n-)
```

and replace with:

```
- $1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO0Vco/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([A-Z])`: Match an uppercase letter and capture in group #1
- `(?=.*\r?\n-)`: Lookahead to assert presence of `-` on next line